# Adding a column containing screen-scraped values to a CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I am working on building a map of building permits issued in El Paso, TX. This is my first foray into the wonderful world of python, and it's been fun, but I cannot figure out the csv module to save my life.

I have a .csv file containing the fields 'Date', 'Building Number', 'Building Type', 'Description', 'Project Name', 'Expiration Date', 'Status', to which I need to add a column called "address" with the address associated with each building number.

I have got the code to get the address using the building permit number down, but I am at a loss as to how to get each building number in sequence, use it to get the address for the permit, then write it to the new 'address' column. why they couldn't have just put the address in the .csv file in the first place is beyond me.

here's what I've got so far to get the address:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

CaseNo = "RSP11-00459"    # this is an example of the building permit number format
DBaseEntry = urllib.urlopen("http://permits.elpasotexas.gov/tm_bin/tmw_cmd.pl?tmw_cmd=StatusViewCase&shl_caseno=%s " % CaseNo)
Soup = BeautifulSoup(DBaseEntry.read())
Dang = Soup.findAll("td", { "class" : "ReportCell"})[5]
Address = str(Dang)
TableEntry = Address[23:-5].strip( )
print TableEntry
```

it's inelegant, but I need a way to get the building number values as CaseNo, then write TableEntry as the value for the (newly created) Address column.
these tables will all have 100 rows each, if it matters.

any thoughts/suggestions?

Comment: Could you please lowercase names? Uppercase names are reserved for classes.

Comment: You say "I cannot figure out the csv module" but then go on to ask a question that's about BeautifulSoup -- could you clarify?  "I need a way to get the building number values as CaseNo" also doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure i fully understand your question, but if it's about using the CSV module, then your code should look something like that:

```
import csv,os

with open('foo.csv', 'rb') as r, open('foo.tmp', 'wb') as w:
    reader = csv.reader(r)
    writer = csv.writer(w)

    for row in reader:
        newrow=whatever_processing_you_need(row)
        writer.writerow(newrow)

os.unlink('foo.csv')
os.rename('foo.tmp','foo.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you got the address using the code you reported and now you want to append this address to your csv file. If it is so, I'd use @bdev solution, and "whatever_processing_you_need" will simply translate into: "find the corresponding row of the address you retrieved and append the last column with the address".